# Error in kile about unable to open PDF file

Tags: 19.10, kile

I've been having a problem with kile and for a long time, I've just ignored it but it's now getting annoying...

While typing in the editor window, I get a message that says, "Could not open file:///tmp/kile-livepreview.RDNKpj/p.pdf".  So, when I look for this file, I do have permissions to access it -- it is the PDF version of what I am typing.

The other strange thing is I only have the editor open; I've closed the preview window.  So, I guess there are two issues:

1. Why is it generating previews when I didn't ask it to (has it been turned 'on' somewhere which I don't know about?)?
2. How come it's complaining about access to a file which I clearly have access to?  Both the file and the path to the file is accessible by my user ID.

Also, it doesn't happen all the time.  Only sometimes...I cannot figure out the pattern of when it appears.  Maybe once every 5 minutes as I type?

It's somewhat annoying that this error pops up while I'm typing.  Has anyone experienced this and/or know what I should do?

This is Ubuntu 19.10, so kile is version 2.9.92 .

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but I had the same problem, and this the first google result, so this might be helpful for future people:

- The problem seems to happen when you type while the document is already compiling, thus triggering a new compilation. This seems to confuse kile about which pdf is ready when.
- Here is a bug-report for the problem: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=417757
- Switching the setting from "compile documents whenever there are changes after X" to "compile documents after saving" circumvents the problem. Of course thats somewhat less convenient, but at least not annying you with popups.

Comment: I still haven't solved my problem yet, but I will certainly give this a try!  Thank you!  I actually always compile on the command-line so if that's the cause, I will happily do what you suggest.  Thank you for posting your solution (and making a new account to do it?).  I'll accept as soon as I check it out myself later this week.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the pdf file '/tmp/kile-livepreview.RDNKpj/p.pdf' worked for me as a workaround whenever that happens. For example you could do in a terminal:

```
rm /tmp/kile-livepreview.RDNKpj/p.pdf
```

hope this helps :)